# Create JIRA issue from SharePoint using Logic apps

Tags: jira, sharepoint-online, azure-logic-apps

I want to create a JIRA issue using Logic Apps when a row is inserted into a SharePoint online list.  I've authenticated myself, but am getting this error.  The main part of the message reads as follows:
Field ‘reporter’ of type ‘user’ is not supported.  More diagnostic information: x-ms-client-request-id is ’71…’
The Logic App action is "create a new issue V2". The previous version seems to work OK, but has been deprecated.
The SharePoint list also has some rich text fields.  Will I be able to upload them?  Looking at the [JIRA connector documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/jira/#createissueresponse) I suspect not, but would like to check.

[image: Logic App error message]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve this, you need to remove the 'reporter' field from the JIRA Issue Type you are using in the Create a new issue task in Logic Apps.

Comment: Yep... like the error said. Not every field is compatible with JIRA. They accept single line of text, number, and date/datetime. Otherwise, you get the error.